# How do I call a method from another class?

Tags: java, class, methods, java-7

I am having problems accessing a method that is in a separate class, when I try to call it from my main class. This is the method

```
class RobotData
{
    private int junctionRecorder(IRobot robot)
    {
        int[] juncX;
        int[] juncY;
        int[] arrived;
        int[] junctions;
        int i = 0;
    i = junctions[0];
    juncX[i] = robot.getLocationX();
    juncY[i] = robot.getLocationY();
    arrived[i] = robot.getHeading();
    junctions[0]++;
    return i;
    }
}
```

and when I try to call it in my main class, using

```
public class Test
{
    public void controlRobot(IRobot robot)
    {
    int recordjunction = junctionRecorder(robot);
        //...
```

it comes up with this error

```
Test.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method junctionRecorder
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make an instance of object to call its method (if it's not static):

```
public class Test
{
  public void controlRobot(IRobot robot)
  {
    RobotData rd = new RobotData();
    int recordjunction = rd.junctionRecorder(robot);
    //...
```

Or something like this (I supose you wanted to do this):

```
public class Test
{
  public void controlRobot(IRobot robot)
  {
    int recordjunction = robot.junctionRecorder(robot);
    //...
```

But in this case class `RobotData` have to implement interface `IRobot`:

```
class RobotData implements IRobot
```

And also method `junctionRecorder` is `private`, you have to make it `public`.

Anyway, I think that you should first read about fundamentals (like objects, instances, creating them etc.) and be sure that you understand it.

Comment: Thanks - thats really helpful. Now I just need to check that I'm using arrays right, as it comes up with more errors. Am I doing anything wrong with juncX, juncY, and arrived?

Comment: @Connor, you have to initialize an array with its size. `int[] arrives = new int[10];`  If you do not do that you will not have any places to put your values.  (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)